# Postgresql - access/use joined subquery result in another joined subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a database with tables for

- equipment we service (table `e`, field `e_id`)
- contracts on the equipment (table `c`, fields `c_id`, `e_id`, `c_start`, `c_end`)
- maintenance we have performed in the past (table `m`, `e_id`, `m_id`,
  `m_date`)

I am trying to build a query that will show me all equipment records, if it is currently in contract with the start/end date, and a count of any maintenance performed since the start date of the contract.

I have a subquery to get the current contract (this table is large and has a new line for each contract revision), but I can't work out how to use the result of the contract subquery to return the maintenance visits since that date without returning multiple lines.

```
select
  e.e_id,
  c2.c_id,
  c2.c_start,
  c2.c_end,
  m2.count
from e
left join (
  select
  c_id,
  c_start,
  c_end,
  e_id
  ...other things and filtering by joining the table to itself
  from c
) as c2 on c2.e_id = e.e_id
```

I would also like to be able to add this
**m-subquery v1**

```
left join (
  select
  count(*),
  e_id
  from m
  where m.m_date >= c2.start
) as m2 on m2.e_id = e.e_id
```

But I'm unable to access `c2.C_start` from within the second subquery.

I am able to return this table by joining outside the subquery, but this returns multiple lines.
**m-subquery v2**

```
left join (
  select
  e_id,
  m_date,
  from m
) as m2 on m2.e_id = e.e_id and m.m_date >= c2.start
```

Is there a way to:

- Get the subquery field c2.start into the m-subquery v1?
- Aggregate the result of the m-subquery v2 without using group by (there are a lot of columns in the main select query)?
- Do this differently?

I've seen `lateral` which I kind of think might be what I need but I have tried the keyword in front of both subqueries individually and together and it didn't work to let me use c2.c_start inside at any point.

I am a little averse to using group by, mainly as the BI analyst at work says "slap a group by on it" when there are duplicates in reports rather than trying to understand the business process/database properly. I feel like having a group by on the main query shouldn't be needed when I know for certain that the `e` table has one record per `e_id`, and the mess that having probably 59 out of 60 columns named in the group by would cause might make the query less maintainable.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Would it be possible to create each subquery as a view? You can treat views as if they were tables in your queries, joining across views and so on.

Comment: This would probably have been what I'd have ended up doing, but the `WITH subquery_name AS (SELECT...)` below seems to basically do this without having to maintain multiple views/queries for one report. Views would probably be better if I was going to re-use the subqueries elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since not all RDBMS support `lateral`, I would like to present you the following general solution. You can make use of [CTEs (WITH queries)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) to help structuring the query and reuse partial results. E.g. in the following code, you can think of current_contracts as a kind of virtual table existing only during query execution.

**Part 1: DDLs and test data**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS e;
CREATE TABLE e
(
  e_id INTEGER
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;
CREATE TABLE c
(
  c_id INTEGER,
  e_id INTEGER,
  c_start DATE,
  c_end DATE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m;
CREATE TABLE m
(
  e_id INTEGER,
  m_id INTEGER,
  m_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO e VALUES (101),(102),(103);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (201, 101, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31'), (202, 102, DATE '2021-03-01', DATE '2021-04-15'), (203, 102, DATE '2021-04-16', DATE '2021-04-30'), (204, 103, DATE '2003-01-01', DATE '2003-12-31'), (205, 103, DATE '2021-04-01', DATE '2021-04-30');
INSERT INTO m VALUES (101, 301, DATE '2021-01-01'), (101, 302, DATE '2021-02-01'), (101, 303, DATE '2021-03-01'), (102, 304, DATE '2021-04-02'), (102, 305, DATE '2021-04-03'), (103, 306, DATE '2021-04-03');
```

**Part 2: the actual query**

```
WITH
-- find currently active contracts per equipment:
-- we assume there is 0 or 1 contract active per equipment at any time
current_contracts AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM c
  WHERE c.c_start <= CURRENT_DATE  -- only active contracts
    AND c.c_end   >= CURRENT_DATE  -- only active contracts
),

-- count maintenance visits during the (single) active contract per equipment, if any:
current_maintenance AS
(
  SELECT m.e_id, COUNT(*) AS count_m_per_e  -- a count of maintenance visits per equipment
  FROM m
  INNER JOIN current_contracts cc
     ON cc.e_id = m.e_id        -- match maintenance to current contracts via equipment
    AND cc.c_start <= m.m_date  -- only maintenance that was done during the current contract
  GROUP BY m.e_id
)

-- bring the parts together for our result:
-- we start with equipment and use LEFT JOINs to assure we retain all equipment
SELECT 
  e.*, 
  cc.c_start, cc.c_end, 
  CASE WHEN cc.e_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS has_contract,
  COALESCE(cm.count_m_per_e, 0)  -- to replace NULL when no contract is active
FROM e
LEFT JOIN current_contracts cc
   ON cc.e_id = e.e_id
LEFT JOIN current_maintenance cm
   ON cm.e_id = e.e_id
ORDER BY e.e_id;
```

Please note that your real pre-processing logic for contracts and maintenance visits may be more complex, e.g. due to overlapping periods of active contracts per equipment.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked. Essentially this seems to be like defining a view and using it in the query (as suggested by @don-r above), just doing it all in one go and without having to drop and replace everything if you needed to change the underlying view.